# Base64 Into Base64

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, base64

I have this:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("foobar");
var base64_text = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
Console.WriteLine(base64_text);
```

The code above works perfectly, but I have one question. Is it programmatically possible to encode the encoded string into 2x encoded string again?

However, if you are trying to decrypt them, it would results in the same and normal text. if Yes, then please provide the code and guide them. If No, then please explain. Lastly, Would it be possible if I decode it many times (let's say a 100) using base64? And would the size increase? I am not doing this as a main way to encrypt stuff (just to let people know).

Comment: You can Base64-encode the results as many times as you'd like, but you would have to decode the result the same number of times.

Comment: Base64 has nothing to do with encryption. It is a character encoding that limits the characters in the output string to printable characters. It is often used to encode binary data so that it can be sent over character only transport protocols.

Comment: Encryption requires a (secret) key, decoding doesn't. If you don't enter a key somewhere, there is no encryption. You only ever need to encode data once, as it is used to go from one format (bytes) to another (textual string). How base 64 works is clearly described on Wikipedia, including the size increase. -1 for not looking up basic information or trying yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already doing everything you need to try this yourself:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("foobar");
var base64_text = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
Console.WriteLine(base64_text);

data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64_text);
base64_text = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
Console.WriteLine(base64_text);
```

You'll see that the data changes and grows every time you perform the encoding, and you can imagine you'd need to perform the decode operation the same number of times to get the original string back.

As already said, no matter how often you Base64-*encode* a string, it will never be a decent encryption mechanism. For instance, if you change something in the *beginning* of the original string, something will change in the *beginning* of the Base64 encoded value, regardless of how many times you've repeated it.

`foobar` encoded up to 4 times:

```
Zm9vYmFy
Wm05dlltRnk=
V20wNWRsbHRSbms9
VjIwd05XUnNiSFJTYm1zOQ==
```

`doobar` encoded up to 4 times:

```
ZG9vYmFy 
Wkc5dlltRnk= 
V2tjNWRsbHRSbms9 
VjJ0ak5XUnNiSFJTYm1zOQ==
```

And the equals characters (`=` or `==`) that often appear on the end of the encoded string are a quick giveaway that you're using Base64.

Comment: ... and the rather restricted alphabet (set of characters used) will be a quick giveaway otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to base64-encode a string multiple times you can use some code like this:

```
string text = "foobar";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    text = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text));       
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Just Create these functions :

```
 public string  Encode (string EncodingText,int NumberOfTimesYouWantToEncode)
    {
        byte[] data;
        string base64_text = EncodingText;
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfTimesYouWantToEncode; i++)
        {
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64_text);
            base64_text = Convert.ToBase64String(data);

        }
        return base64_text;
    }


    public string Decode(string EncodingText, int NumberOfTimesYouNeedToDecode)
    {
        byte[] data;
        string decodedString = EncodingText;
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfTimesYouNeedToDecode; i++)
        {
            data = Convert.FromBase64String(decodedString);
            decodedString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
        }
        return decodedString;
    }
```

//And call these function as follow:

```
 string EncodedString= Encode ("foobar", 3);
 string DecodedString=Decode(EncodedString,3);
```